# Using a for loop in python to generate mySQL insert statements

Tags: python, mysql

I am working on a python script to take an incoming String of data from several arduinos to read, split and insert that data into a database.

The problem is the sensor data varies in the number of values depending on what kind of sensor is used.  I cannot figure out the proper way to loop through the separated pieces and insert them properly.

A '1' specifies 10HS sensor and need 1 space for the incoming value
The String comes in like this for 10HS sensors:

"Cucumber2015,Arduino01,1,20150918124200,25.3,75.5,***1*,12   .....** 


A '2' specifies 10HS sensor and need 1 space for the incoming value
"Cucumber2015,Arduino01,1,20150918124200,25.3,75.5,***2*,12,24,23  ......**

The for loop should repeat until all the sensor values have an insert statement for their respective tables.

I have tried the code shown below and keep getting errors.

How can I accomplish this?  Besides the syntax problem, am I going about this correctly?

**My current error**

```
  File "serialToDbV3.py", line 50
    index =index+1
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Python code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial 
import MySQLdb

#establish connection to MySQL. You'll have to change this for your database.
dbConn =     MySQLdb.connect("localhost","python_user","password","IrrigationDB") or die ("could not connect to database")
#open a cursor to the database
cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = '/dev/ttyUSB0' #this will have to be changed to the serial port you are using
baudrate = 9600

def getSerialData():
try:
    print "Trying...",device
    arduino = serial.Serial(device, baudrate) 
except: 
    print "Failed to connect on",device    

try:
    print "Trying to get data"
    next(arduino)
    data = arduino.readline()  #read the data from the Arduino
    pieces = data.split(",")  #split the data by the tab
    print "Data: %s" % data
    print "Piece 0: ProjectID %s" % pieces[0]
    print "Piece 1: ArduinoID %s" % pieces[1]
    print "Piece 2: Plot#     %s" % pieces[2]
    print "Piece 3: SQLTime   %s" % pieces[3]
    print "Piece 4: AirTemp   %s" % pieces[4]
    print "Piece 5: Humidity  %s" % pieces[5]
    print "Piece 6: SensType  %s" % pieces[6]
    print "Piece 7: SensData  %s" % pieces[7]
    print "Piece 8:           %s" % pieces[8]
    print "Piece 9:          %s" % pieces[9]
    print "Piece 10:          %s" % pieces[10]
#Here we are going to insert the data into the Database
    try:
        print "Trying insertion..."
        cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO `IrrigationDB`.`Project`(`idProject`)VALUES (%s)", (pieces[0]))     
        cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO `IrrigationDB`.`Arduino`(`idArduino`,`FK_ProjectID`)VALUES (%s,%s)", (pieces[1],pieces[0]))     
        cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO `IrrigationDB`.`Plot`(`idPlot`,`FK_ArduinoID`)VALUES (%s,%s)", (pieces[2],pieces[1]))       
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `IrrigationDB`.`Reading`(`DateAndTime`,`airTempC`,`relativeHumidity`,`FK_PlotID`)VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (pieces[3],pieces[4],pieces[5],pieces[2]))       

        startingPosition = 6
        for index in xrange(startingPosition, len(pieces), step):
            if pieces[6] == 1 :
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `IrrigationDB`.`10HS_Sensor`(`id10HS_Sensor`,`DielectricPermittivity`)VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (pieces[2],pieces[i+1])
                index =index+1
            if pieces[6] == 2 :
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `IrrigationDB`.`GS3_Sensor`(`idGS3_Sensor`,`DielectricPermittivity`,`soilTempC`,`electricalConductivity`)VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (pieces[2],pieces[i+1],pieces[i+2],pieces[i+3]))
                index=index+3
    except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
        print "failed to insert data"         
except:
    print "Failed to get data from Arduino!" 

val = 0
while val == 0 :
    getSerialData()
```

Comment: You're missing a closing paren on the previous line.

Comment: correct about missing ).  You should put a try/except Exception around each cursor.execute.  That way you would know which one blows up.  IntegrityError is too restrictive, that would probably not cover a malformed sql for example. I doubt you need ` around each table/column name, unless you had something like a **My Table** with spaces (best avoided).

Answer (score 0):

Use proper exception reporting, at least until you get to end-user land.

```
try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO `IrrigationDB`.`Project`(`idProject`)VALUES (%s)", (pieces[0]))     
except Exception, e:
    print "this is sql #6", e
    raise
```

This will tell you more clearly what is going on, which you can then post here.

Comment: Thanks! I will implement your suggestion.